# errors when installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I just downloaded ruby 2.6.5 and as well as sqlite3. I followed the tutorial to install rails and typed "gem install rails" in the command prompt but ran into this error. I have no idea what these things are and have been stuck here for quite a long time. Could someone give me some advice on this please? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
C:\>gem install rails
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: D:/ruby files/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1/ext/websocket-driver
D:/ruby\ files/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I D:/ruby\ files/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20191228-14032-rudo55.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: D:/ruby files/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR=" clean
Makefile:269: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

current directory: D:/ruby files/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR="
Makefile:269: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in D:/ruby files/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/ruby files/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/websocket-driver-0.7.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: This is a pretty wild guess, but `make` generally reacts very badly to filenames with spaces in them. Can you rename `ruby files` to something like `ruby_files` so that it doesn’t contain a space? You may need to reinstall whatever else is in there for it to have a proper effect.

Comment: Can you give the logs from log file ?

Comment: To reinforce @simonwo's advice, I recommend _never_ using spaces in names of files and directories that you intend to use, or be used by, the command line. I'm wondering if you have the compilers and tools necessary to build native gems. You can test this by `gem install nokogiri`; that _might_ give you a more specific error message.